# Tensorflow seq2seq: Tensor' object is not iterable

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, sequence-to-sequence

I am using seq2seq below code, I found below error:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(size)
a, b = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, seq_input, dtype=tf.float32)
cell_a = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, frame_dim)
dec_output= tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder(seq_input, b, cell_a)
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

I checked and it comes from seq2seq line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `seq_input` is a tensor, not a list of tensors. A single tensor works fine for `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, but [`rnn_decoder`](http://tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder) requires unstacking the sequence into a list of tensors:

> `decoder_inputs`: A list of 2D Tensors `[batch_size x input_size]`.

In the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L112), you can see that the implementation simply iterates over `decoder_inputs` in a `for` loop.